# ¿Como obtener el valor proximo mas cercano?

Tags: javascript, array, object, filtro

Tengo una función en la que itero por un array de objetos anidados, cuyo objetivo es crear conexiones entre diferentes cajas. En mi función puedo hacer un primer filtro en el que obtengo las diferentes opciones de combinación entre las cajas, pero después de este paso necesito quedarme sólo con el que devuelve el siguiente valor más cercano de una de la propiedad "order" de cada objeto. Por ejemplo, cuando estoy en la caja 1, cuya propiedad de "order" es 1 y puede ser combinada con cualquier número de cajas, sólo necesito quedarme con aquella cuya propiedad de orden es el siguiente valor más cercano, el cual no tiene porque ser secuencial. Impidiendo que se pueda conectar con una que tenga un valor menor y que la que tenga el valor de orden más alto de todas tampoco se pueda conectar .

```
for (const indexBox in boxes) {
      if (boxes.hasOwnProperty(indexBox)) {
        const box = boxes[indexBox];
        const combinations = box.filter(b => b.properties.order !== box.properties.order);
     }
}
```

my array

```
[
  {
    x: 200,
    y: 350,
    properties: {
      order: 1,
      name: "A",
      input: {
        0: { id: 1, boxId: 1, color: "azul" },
        1: { id: 2, boxId: 1, color: "rojo" },
      },
      output: {
        0: { id: 1, boxId: 1, color: "azul" },
        1: { id: 2, boxId: 1, color: "rojo" },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    x: 600,
    y: 550,
    properties: {
      order: 2,
      name: "B",
      input: {
        0: { id: 1, boxId: 2, color: "azul" },
        1: { id: 2, boxId: 2, color: "rojo" },
      },
      output: { 0: { id: 1, boxId: 2, color: "verde" } },
    },
  },
  {
    x: 100,
    y: 450,
    properties: {
      order: 3,
      name: "C",
      input: {
        0: { id: 1, boxId: 3, color: "azul" },
        1: { id: 2, boxId: 3, color: "verde" },
      },
      output: {
        0: { id: 1, boxId: 3, color: "azul" },
        1: { id: 2, boxId: 3, color: "rojo" },
      },
    },
  },
]
```

Necesito encontrar el modo de obneter el siguiente valor mas cercano porque puede darse el caso de que se eliminen cajas durante la iteraccion del usuario, por lo que el orden de los valores puede no ser secuencial.
Gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se te puede dar un código concreto porque no dices concretamente por qué propiedad vas a realizar la criba. Dices "necesito quedarme sólo con el que devuelve el siguiente valor más cercano de *una de las propiedades* de cada objeto", aunque luego das el ejemplo de `orden`.

Yo lo enfocaría así:

Primero, como dices en tu planteamiento, filtras las cajas por el criterio que quieras:

```
let cajas_filtradas = cajas.filter(<tu función de filtrado>);
```

Luego, dado el campo y el valor de la caja "base", te quedas con las que tienen un valor mayor:

```
let indice_de_la_caja_que_me_interesa = 3,
    campo = 'order',
    orden = cajas[indice_de_la_caja_que_me_interesa].properties[campo];

let cajas_mayores = cajas_filtradas.filter(caja => caja.properties[campo] > orden);
```

Y por último
, te quedas con la de menor valor (de las que son mayores):

```
let caja_menor_de_las_mayores = cajas_mayores.reduce(function (acum, caja) {
    if (acum === null) {
        return caja;
    }
    if (caja.properties[campo] < acum.properties[campo]) {
        return caja;
    } else {
        return acum;
    }
}, null);
```

El código ejecutable:

```js
let cajas = [
  { x: 200, y: 350, properties: { order: 1, name: "A", }, },
  { x: 600, y: 550, properties: { order: 7, name: "B", }, },
  { x: 200, y: 350, properties: { order: 5, name: "C", }, },
  { x: 600, y: 550, properties: { order: 15, name: "D", }, },
  { x: 200, y: 350, properties: { order: 10, name: "E", }, },
  { x: 600, y: 550, properties: { order: 12, name: "F", }, },
  { x: 200, y: 350, properties: { order: 16, name: "G", }, },
  { x: 600, y: 550, properties: { order: 9, name: "H", }, },
  { x: 200, y: 350, properties: { order: 6, name: "I", }, },
  { x: 600, y: 550, properties: { order: 11, name: "J", }, },
];

// La caja con indice 1 tiene el orden 7, con lo cual
// el resultado debería ser la caja con orden 9

let indice_de_la_caja_que_me_interesa = 1,
    campo = 'order',
    orden = cajas[indice_de_la_caja_que_me_interesa].properties[campo];

let resultado = cajas.filter(x => true)
                     .filter(caja => caja.properties[campo] > orden)
                     .reduce(function (acum, caja) {
    if (acum === null) {
        return caja;
    } else if (caja.properties[campo] < acum.properties[campo]) {
        return caja;
    }
    return acum;
}, null);

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: muchas gracias! me ha ayudado mucho

Comment: De nada! Intenta dividir siempre en pasos, y muy importante, utiliza las funciones `filter()`, `reduce()`, `map()`, `find()`, `every()` y `some()` de `Array` siempre que puedas. Te simplificarán la vida.